# Get last access date with forfiles

Tags: batch-file, forfiles

I need some assistance with getting the forfiles command:

```
forfiles /S /M "*.exe" /C "cmd /C echo @Path @ISDIR @Fdate @Ftime @Fsize" >> Output.txt
```

Comment: I wanted to show last access date instead of last modified date.

Comment: Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: By default "@fdate" will only show last modified. Can I echo out last access date?

Answer (score 0):

The last access date is not something that `FORFILES` produces. It can be done in a .bat file script using PowerShell.

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter '*.exe' |" ^
        "ForEach-Object {'""{0}""" {1} {2} {3}' -f @($_.FullName, $_.PSIsContainer, $_.LastAccessTime, $_.Length) }"
```

Output:

```
"C:\src\t\renexe\bar.exe" False 2018-02-16 02:19:51 6
"C:\src\t\renexe\baz.exe" False 2018-02-16 02:19:51 6
"C:\src\t\renexe\foo.exe" False 2018-02-16 02:19:51 6
```

Comment: @RoyHo - Really? What version of Windows are you running? Please consider including your Windows version in any questions here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dir` command to help out, like this

```
forfiles /M *.xml /C "cmd /c dir /ta @file | findstr /R ^\d"
```

where the `findstr` filters for convenience.

Comment: I would need to export it out to Excel format.. can you script be done?

Comment: Yes. Pipe the output into a file, and read that file with a `for` loop, echo the 2 strings per line as "%%a,%%b", that is, separated by a comma, and pipe that into a file 'dates.csv'. Or maybe you can import the script's output directly.